# Export to PDF for printing option in web application using Servlet/jsps

Tags: jsp, servlets

My application is a web based reporting tool. The reports are generated from some input parameters that are received from jsps. The results are processed through Servlets then displayed back again using jsps.

Now on the report page we need a button that on clicking will export the generated report to pdf for printing. But I am at my wits end on how to do this.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On click on Export to PDF button again submit the page to the same servlet but at the end of doPost method of your servlet write below code as

```
if(request.getParameter("exportPDFButtonName") != null) {
     response.setContentType("application/pdf");
     response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=reportfile.pdf");
}
```

Comment: just by setting the content type to pdf won't help. At best it opens the Adobe Reader with an error message that document is damaged or not the proper format., But thanks anyway for answering